# How to use the results in dataset for a select statement in C#

Tags: c#, sql

My intentions is to get a value to a string using a select statement from the database at Visual studio and use that string variable to obtain a result of another select statement and execute it.

my intention is to do something like this,

```
 string qry = "SELECT vehicle_no FROM User_table  WHERE username='" + userName + "' ;";
 string query = "SELECT longitude,latitude FROM Gps_table  WHERE vehicle_no='" + qry + "';"; 

 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(qry, dbConnection);

 if (reader.HasRows)
 {
     while (reader.Read())
     {
         gpsTable.Rows.Add(reader["longitude"], reader["latitude"]);
     }
 }

 reader.Close();
 dbConnection.Close();
 return gpsTable;
```

But i found out that this cannot be done and that i have to use a dataset for the first select statement. How can i get the required task done. PLease Help !!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, use parameterized queries. Why do you need to execute two separate queries? Why not combine them? It's not really clear what the problem is here..

Comment: Any reason you're not just doing a join? Btw, you really shouldn't build SQL like that - it's vulnerable to [SQL Injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: your query is not well formated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just this (and mind username `"'; DROP DATABASE * ;"`    ;)

```
     string query = "SELECT longitude,latitude FROM Gps_table  
WHERE vehicle_no
IN
( 
      SELECT vehicle_no FROM User_table  WHERE username='" + userName + "' 
)

"; 

     SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, dbConnection);

     if (reader.HasRows)
     {
         while (reader.Read())
         {
             gpsTable.Rows.Add(reader["longitude"], reader["latitude"]);
         }
     }

     reader.Close();
     dbConnection.Close();
     return gpsTable;
```

What I mean is: 
In your SQL-Statement, I can create a USER with name "'; DROP DATABASE * ;".
Then when you execute the query, it will drop the database, because the ' in the string terminates the variable, and the drop database sql statement is injected into your command...

Comment: Thank you for the answer, can you please be kind enough to tell me what you have meant by mind username,drop database ??? Also the value passed to SqlCommand should be query ???? or qry ????

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SqlCommand command = Connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT G.longitude,G.latitude " +
                      "FROM Gps_table G Inner Join User_table U ON G.vehicle_no=U.vehicle_no  " +
                      "WHERE U.username=@username;";

command.Parameter.Add("@username", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = userName;
```

With DataTable

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command)
DataTable dt = New DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

dgv.DataSource = dt;
```

With SqlDataReader

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    While (reader.Read())
    {
        gpsTable.Rows.Add(reader["longitude"], reader["latitude"]);
    }
}  
reader.Close();
```